# php form validation using session variable

Tags: php, forms, validation, session

I have a sign-up form in php, which sends data to another php form for insertion into mysql

If any of the fields are missing, an error mesage is sent back to sign-up form using session variable `(value="<?php echo $_SESSION['error']; ?>")` along with all the fields the user had already filled up ( so that they dont have to fill it up again ) using session variables as well..

for text boxes im using `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?>"` which works fine.. but this doesnt seem to work for drop down boxes  or radio buttons..

any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm.. trying to imagine what is source code, hmm... I failed. Please post it here, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop down boxes and radio buttons use a selected or click index. You need to check for each one if it was selected or clicked and give it the appropriate attribute.

```
 <?php if($_SESSION['dropBox1'] == "value") echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't submit the form to another page for validation. Do it in the current page. And drop down lists and radio buttons `value` attribute is the value that is tied to the selection. Not what is displayed or in any way tells it that it is the selected item. @James beat me for code on how to show which is selected.

```
<select>
  <option value="0"  <?php echo $_SESSION['dropBox1'] == "0" ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>>option1</option>
  <option value="1"  <?php echo $_SESSION['dropBox1'] == "1" ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>>option2</option>
  <option>etc..</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Shredder, the original form was in html.. which is the reason why i had it post to separate php for submission, i just changed the form to php to get the session functionality.. ( are there any benefits of having it post to itself?) thanks

Comment: @ABI Even if it is in html, you can use javascript to do your form validation *before* submission. This is convenient for the user so they don't have to wait for 1 (or 2 in the case of validating in another page) http requests cycles. It is instant, done on the client. If the data is good, then you can post it to your other page for mysql insert

Comment: using the ternary operator you don't havemto specify `echo`

Comment: @Marcx Yes, you need `echo` in there